# jQuery AJAX Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jQuery UI code:

```
            $('#lang-dialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false
            });


            $('a#lang').click(function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault(); $('#lang-dialog').dialog('open');
            });
```

This allows a link to load up a dialog box instead of doing it's using hypertransfer.

However their is no `#lang-dialog` on the page as instead I want to create it using jQuery and then use AJAX to load in the contents so for example: `$('#lang-dialog').load('/elements/dialogs/language.ctp');`

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Just add a `<div id=lang-dialog></div>` to the page.  What is the problem here?

Comment: Don't want empty markup on the page and the div also needs to dynamically load the content.

Comment: That's a really poor reason, imho. You're only going to slow down the experience by creating and loading it AFTER the user clicks. Rob provided an answer with dynamic creation though...

Comment: It's not though as empty markup is bad design and appending a DIV using jQuery is actually faster because then only people who click the link will load that DIV.

Answer (score 1):

As Fosco mentions, add this before you call `.dialog()`:

```
$('body').append('<div id="lang-dialog"></div>');
```

If it's a method that may get called more than once:

```
// prevent multiple div's from being added...
if(!$('#lang-dialog').length){
    $('body').append('<div id="lang-dialog"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the Ajax logic yourself instead of using `.load()`:

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
  $('some-parent-element').append('<div id="lang-dialog"></div>');
  $('#lang-dialog').html(html).dialog({
    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a html element on the fly as shown below.

```
var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog" title=""></div>').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });
```